# colouring a graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coloring

In a given graph with $n$ vertices ,the degree of each vertex is less than or equal to $5$. Prove that the vertices can  be coloured using only three colors such that the number of edges which have endpoints of same colour is atmost $n/2$

Attempts:
If the graph is a tree than it can be coloured using only 2 colours such that there is no SCE(edge with endpoints of same colour)[image: no sce]

If there exists a cycle of 4 vertices , no. of sce is at most 1(after coloring)
If 5 vertices, then at most 2
If 6 vertices than at most 3.
I wasn't able to proof for more and also for combinations of cycles

Comment: Why isn't $K_6$ a counterexample? How do you colour the vertices with $3$ colours so that there are $\lt3$ SCE's??

Comment: For $\le n/2$ SCE, S. Dolan's (deleted) answer works. You only need the second paragraph. If the $3$-colouring is chosen to minimise the number of SCE then no vertex is incident with two SCE, i.e., the set of SCE is a matching, so there are at most $n/2$ of them. But I wonder if $n=6$ isn't the only place the original statement ($\lt n/2$ SCE) fails?

Comment: Can you post dolan's answer? I doubt for n=8 let me check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and no vertex of degree greater than $5$. Then $3$-colour $G$ so as to minimise the number of SCE.

First suppose a vertex $v$ of colour $c$ is incident with two SCE. Then there is a colour $d$ such that $v$ is adjacent to at most one vertex of colour $d$. Changing $v$s colour to $d$ then reduces the number of SSE, a contradiction.

Each vertex is now joined to at most $1$ SCE. The total number of SCE is therefore less than or equal to $n/2$, as required.

Comment: @bof Yes, thanks. The point you raised in the comments about when $n/2$ is necessary is interesting. Do you think the graph actually has to be the union of copies of $K_6$ or have you visualised more complicated examples?

Comment: It is uploaded. Can you not see it?

Comment: Yeah, it just appeared now

Comment: My only counterexample was $K_6$. I didn't even think of multiples of $K_6$.